# How to deploy react project to AWS s3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3

I tried to deploy react project to s3, and I followed every step of this instruction.
https://medium.com/@omgwtfmarc/deploying-create-react-app-to-s3-or-cloudfront-48dae4ce0af

However, I cannot see my project on s3 server, and I always get these 2 errors.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Should I change anything?

Here is the file structore
[image]

Here is the first three lines of generated `main.js`

```
!function(e){function t(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var o=n[r]={exports:{},id:r,loaded:!1};return e[r].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,t),o.loaded=!0,o.exports}var n={};return t.m=e,t.c=n,t.p="/",t(0)}(function(e){for(var t in e)if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t))switch(typeof e[t]){case"function":break;case"object":e[t]=function(t){var n=t.slice(1),r=e[t[0]];return function(e,t,o){r.apply(this,[e,t,o].concat(n))}}(e[t]);break;default:e[t]=e[e[t]]}return e}([function(e,t,n){
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? Like what you file look like, where do you get the error etc. Without those, it's impossible to provide any suggestion.

Comment: @AnamulHasan, Thank you for your reply. I just attached the file structure and the generated main.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your cloudfront origin access identity has no permission to access your s3 bucket. You have to update the bucket policy to allow access from cloudfront or update the cloud front origin settings to create an origin identity and automatically update bucket policy.

You can do this from cloud front, by going to origins and editing the s3 origin as in the following screen shot.

[image]

Else if you want to do this from s3 bucket, have a look at the topic "Granting Permission to an Amazon CloudFront Origin Identity" in the following aws documentation.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-6